# Cannot wrap text in the new Python IDLE 3.12.2 on Windows

Tags: python, python-idle

I am unable to wrap text in the script window in Python IDLE 3.12.2 . I saw the previous solutions of clicking on Configure IDLE and then clicking on the General Tab, but this does not exist anymore.

I occasionally write long commands and would like them to wrap instead of scrolling/navigating back and forth.

Is there any solution?

Comment: The General tab was replaced by Window and Shell/Ed tabs.  Shell does wrap.  Editor does not.  The is no option to change wrapping, but there is to open windows wider than 80 columns.150-200 should be enough for most people.

Comment: Thanks @TerryJanReedy! I don’t know why they flagged the question though.

Comment: I am the main IDLE IDE maintainer.  This is one of the cleanest IDLE questions I have seen, and I answered it in my first comment.  I see no trace of the claimed "recommendation request" given as an excuse for closing, even before my edit.  I hope the next people reading will click the Reopen button.

Answer (score 0):

[Copied from comment after reopened.]
The General tab was replaced by Window and Shell/Ed tabs.

Shell does wrap. Editor does not. The is no option to change wrapping, but there is to open windows wider than 80 columns.150-200 should be enough for most people.